# How to train LSTM with previous cell's prediction as an input in Keras?

Tags: keras, frameworks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

At the moment I'm using a simple Keras model to learn a sequence of items and after it using the trained model to generate new sequences . 
I want to change the training to be in the same manner as the generation phase - meaning I want the model to learn from it's own last step's prediction (and I will use the ground truth in the loss function) . 
Is it possible to do in Keras ?

This is the simple model I have now:

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(seq_length, X_train.shape[2]) , return_sequences=True))
model1.add(Dense(y_cat_train.shape[2], activation='softmax'))
model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model1.fit(X_train, y_cat_train, epochs=200, batch_size=10, verbose=2,callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

`X_train` is actually 2 features : `[prev step's true y, prev step's other feature]`